# Creating a matrix with column or row vectors as arguments

Tags: matrices, vector

At times it's convenient to write a matrix in terms of it's row or column component vectors instead of explicitly giving each particular scalar entry. I'm basically talking about this:

[image]

I did some research, but I couldn't find any way to express a matrix in this way.

Answer (score 17):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% Vertically stacked
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \vert & \vert \\
    v_1   & v_2   \\
    \vert & \vert
\end{bmatrix}
\]

% Horizontally stacked
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \text{---} & v_1 & \text{---} \\
    \text{---} & v_2 & \text{---}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The white space in the horizontal matrix can be reduced *ad-hoc*, using `\hspace{}`. For example:

```
% Horizontally stacked
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    \text{---} \hspace{-0.2cm} & v_1 & \hspace{-0.2cm} \text{---} \\
    \text{---} \hspace{-0.2cm} & v_2 & \hspace{-0.2cm} \text{---}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Producing:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
 \vdots & \vdots \\
 v_1 & v_2\\
 \vdots & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```