# Matrix with column vectors

Tags: matrices

My question is smiliar to [Creating a matrix with column or row vectors as arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367960/creating-a-matrix-with-column-or-row-vectors-as-arguments): I would like to typeset a matrix by indicating just its column vectors.

However the answers in the linked questions suggest things like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
    \vert & \vert \\
    v_1   & v_2   \\
    \vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The downside to this is that the matrix now is three rows high. I would like to have a solution that looks nice next to a 2x2 matrix. I then tried

```
\begin{pmatrix}
   \shortmid  & \shortmid \\[-1ex]
    v_1       & v_2   \\[-1ex]
    \shortmid & \shortmid
\end{pmatrix}
```

which is better, but not good. Also, it is absolutely not suitable for regular use, as it is basically just an ad-hoc solution.

Comment: What if you replace `\vert` with `\phantom{}`?

Comment: I would like to have some sort of vertical bar in order to make it very clear that we are talking about entire columns.

Comment: If you use a notation where column vectors have a different appearance , like `\textbf{v}_1` then you won't need to pad out columns.

Comment: Use `[-0.5ex]` as spacing parameter. It looks more centralized.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes and no. For me as a mathematician, even the notation (v_1,v_2) is crystal clear. The text is for students who are just getting familiar with vectors and matrices. For them, this small visual guidance might help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This overlaps the text with two centered `\rule`s.  I threw in a 1pt gap at the top and bottom of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\spike}[2]% #1 = size of spike, #2 = centered text
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#2}%
  \rlap{\usebox0}%
  \hspace{0.5\wd0}%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rule[\dimexpr \ht0+1pt]{0.5pt}{#1}}% top spike
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\rule[\dimexpr -\dp0-#1-1pt]{0.5pt}{#1}}% bottom spike
  \hspace{0.5\wd0}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
    \spike{5pt}{$v_1$}  & \spike{5pt}{$v_2$}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I was experimenting with a `\shortstack` inside the matrix, but it did not work out. Your solution is easy to use and flexible.

Comment: FWIW, I changed the first line to `\newcommand{\spike}[2][3pt]` so that I do not have to indicate the length of the spike at every invocation.

Comment: I left it variable just to make it easier to experiment with.